# lost my files after mounting a partition as home folder

Tags: mount, data-recovery, home-directory, partitioning

I made a bad mistake .  I mounted a partition as home folder based on this post

[after reinstalling ubuntu my previous home folder mounts as an externall drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678884/after-reinstalling-ubuntu-my-previous-home-folder-mounts-as-an-externall-drive/678890?noredirect=1#comment984707_678890)

and I'v lost all of my files in my preivous home folder . is there any way to recover them ?

Comment: Where was your previous HOME? In case you did not deliberately delete it all your files may still reside there.

Comment: Simply umount the partition, e.g. `sudo umount /home`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't deleted your old home folder then try:

```
mkdir mnt
sudo mount --bind / mnt
```

and navigate to `mnt/home/<username>`

Comment: tnx alot . you save my life :)

Comment: thank you, you save me an entire feature that I haven't  yet committed to our code repository.